# LTV (long term validation) signature in TCPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, tcpdf

**How can the LTV signature be added to the TCPDF?**

As far as all know the OCSP responses and all the timestamps for the validation have to be embedded in the pdf. I did not find any code for this online, can you help me? Any help will help me, I am also ready to commit the code later to the TCPDF repo.

Comment: Please write the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @besciualex I have no code for LTV, for standard signing I come out from http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_052.phps especially from the use of `setSignature()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for PAdES, but TCPDF does not yet support it.